# How to set labels and axes limits for matplotlib.animate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I am writing the below script to fetch the GBP-EUR exchange rate and dynamically plot it using matplotlib, as it stands the script runs ad infinitum and updates the graph, however the labels and axis limits do not appear, how would I do this?

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from yahoo_finance import Currency
from time import time
pound = Currency('GBPEUR')
prices = []
times = []
start = time()
n = 0
def animate(i):
    pound.refresh()
    prices.append(float(pound.get_bid()))
    times.append((time() - start))
    plt.axis([0,max(times),0,(max(prices)+5)])
    plt.xlabel('Time since start, Seconds')
    plt.ylabel('Pound-Euro conversion rate')
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(times,prices)
while True:
    pound.refresh()
    prices.append(float(pound.get_bid()))
    times.append((time() - start))
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1)
    plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself, removing the line `ax1.clear()` sorted it.